# Excel Form working fine but crashing after VB Editor opened

Tags: vba, excel

I have a complex Excel vba project which contains a form that opens on startup using the Auto_Open event. I can close this form and reopen it by calling the Auto_Open event from a button. This works unless I open the VB Editor, if I do that, then I can no longer reopen the form by invoking Auto_Open (the form appears and immediately disappears) and instead have to close and reopen the Excel instance.

I have used MsgBoxes in an attempt to trace the code through to the point where it crashes, but I have been unable to find any issues. I've also tried attaching Visual Studio in an attempt to catch the error without success.

This is very frustrating as I can't debug the behaviour of the form. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Can't you call a code which opens the form on startup so that then you would link the button to this code rather than the Auto_Open one ? The goal here is to avoid linking a button to the Auto_Open code which might create troubles

Comment: Hi Seb, I've tried that too, the thing is - the Auto_Open links fine, until I open the VB Editor. But if I link it to another method further down the chain which also opens the form, the same problem occurs.

Comment: When the editor is opened and you run it with F8 does it crash somewhere or not ?

Comment: No, there is no crash at all, the form just disappears

Comment: In the code you calls in auto_open, is there a part where you close the form?  If that's the case, you might be calling the function twice

Comment: Hmm and if you put a breakpoint on the UserForm_Initialize Sub of your form and run the code, does it stop there ? Have you tried putting some breakpoint at different places in your form ?

Comment: The Auto_Open calls the first form, which opens fine, selecting an entry from this form then opens the second form, which closes immediately.

Comment: Yes I have, I added breakpoints throughout the code and I get all the way through the Activate and Initialise events with the form intact. When it returns, the form just disappears. I've just been testing and have reverted to an older version of the application which doesn't have this problem, so at the moment my plan is to slowly reintroduce my changes to that and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried calling the form this way `MyForm.Show vbModal` ?

Comment: Seb will be able to further assist you here as I cannot reproduce the error at the moment.  Also I would suggest to use both msgbox and debug.print for your testing